# MacOSX shared libraries: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, shared-libraries, clang++

I am having some trouble to compile a code using shared libraries on MacOSX.
I first wrote it on Debian before trying to compile it on MacOSX.

Here is the code:

test.hxx:

```
#ifndef TEST_HXX
#define TEST_HXX

namespace test
{
    class CFoo
    {
        /* data */
    public:
        CFoo (){}
        virtual ~CFoo (){}
        void bar();

    }; /* CFoo */
} /* namespace test */

#endif /* TEST_HXX */
```

test.cxx:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.hxx"

void test::CFoo::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
} /* bar() */
```

other.hxx:

```
#ifndef OTHER_HXX
#define OTHER_HXX

namespace other
{
    class CBar
    {
    public:
        CBar (){}
        virtual ~CBar (){}
        void foo();

    }; /* CBar */
} /* namespace other */

#endif /* OTHER_HXX */
```

other.cxx:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.hxx"
#include "other.hxx"

void other::CBar::foo()
{
    test::CFoo c;
    c.bar();
} /* bar() */
```

main.cxx:

```
#include "other.hxx"

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    other::CBar c;
    c.foo();
    return 0;

} /* main () */
```

And a simple makefile:

```
LIBTEST = libtest.so
LIBOTHER = libother.so


all: $(LIBTEST) $(LIBOTHER)
    g++ -ltest -lother -I. -L. main.cxx

libtest.so: test.o
    g++ -shared  test.o -o $(LIBTEST)

libother.so: other.o
    g++ -shared other.o -o $(LIBOTHER)

test.o: test.cxx test.hxx
    g++ -fPIC -c test.cxx

other.o: other.cxx other.hxx
    g++ -fPIC -c other.cxx

clean:
    $(RM) $(LIBOTHER) $(LIBTEST) test.o other.o a.out
```

So I basically create objects `test.o` and `other.o` and create two shared libraries from them (one per object).

`other.cxx` uses the class contained in `test.cxx` to print `Hello world`.

So this makefile and the code works fine on my Debian but I have a compilation error when trying to compile it on MacOSX:

```
g++ -fPIC -c test.cxx
g++ -shared test.o -o libtest.so
g++ -fPIC -c  other.cxx
g++ -shared other.o -o libother.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::CFoo::bar()", referenced from:
      other::CBar::foo() in other.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libother.so] Error 1
```

It compiles and creates my shared library for `test` but fails when creating `libother.so`.

When using only one shared library (so printing `Hello world` in `main` directly from `test`) it works just fine but the problem occurs when using several shared libraries...

I am not an Apple user and never works on MacOSX before so I don't really understand how linking is being done. And the error doesn't really makes sense to me...

Thank you for helping me to understand this error!

Comment: You're not using `g++` you're using clang (and Apple are lying to you)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `libother` uses `libtest` but you don't link with it. Try

```
g++ -shared other.o -o libother.so -L. -ltest
```

The `-L` tells the compiler where to search for the library, `-l` links with it.